# Declare method in TypeScript to be built into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I declare a method in TypeScript that translates into a method in JavaScript? The JavaScript code I want is shown below

```
function insertrow() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

This is the TypeScript I have so far...

```
public insertRow(){
    console.log('test');
}
```

This is what the TypeScript I have translates into

```
insertRow();
{
    console.log('test');
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to change the typescript so the start of the method in javascript will be function(......)

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Is all that code really relevant or only the first line?

Comment: declaring a method in typescript is as simple as declaring it in any other language example function_name(){}  but once you write a function in typescript and run it will automatically convert it into javascript which u don't have to do manually. which javascript frontend framework are you using.?

Comment: only the 1st line, but im also not sure about how this code works as its my 1st time working on typescript

Comment: i tried to reverse-engineer the javascript code that i wanted by using an online ts to js converter haha

Comment: i am not sure how to declare a method that will connect to my database and run insert queries in typescript... @UmeshMGowda

Comment: node.js @UmeshMGowda

Answer (score 0):

Several things :

1)
 `public` is for function declarations inside a class. Are you defining your function inside a class ? Your question is not clear on that.

2) `public` is already the default modifier for Typescript functions in classes. You can simply omit it, and you should get same result.

3) You can use valid Javascript in Typescript (though maybe with some special compiler option depending on the case). So you can simply declare a global funciton in Typescript as you would do in Javascript (and it will be translated as the same Javascript). [See this example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20testFunction()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('hello')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AtestFunction()%3B)

Comment: I found that my method does not work with function() before i came here to ask, and yes the method is inside a class. I used that TypeScript playground to "reverse-engineer" to the current Typescript code that i have